# Paste from Word to Browser HTML Editor - Images

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, openxml, vml

I have a C# winforms application with a WebBrowser component that has designMode turned on (content-editable), and I want users to be able to copy and paste content from Word into this component.

The majority of it works just fine, except for images. Instead of images coming through as standard IMG HTML tags, I get VML that looks like this (line-breaks added for readability):

```
...HTML up here...
<?xml:namespace prefix="v" ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
<v:shapetype id=_x0000_t75 stroked="f" filled="f" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" o:preferrelative="t" o:spt="75" coordsize="21600,21600">
  <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"></v:stroke>
  <v:formulas>
  <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f>
  <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"></v:f>
</v:formulas>
<v:path o:connecttype="rect" gradientshapeok="t" o:extrusionok="f"></v:path>
<o:lock aspectratio="t" v:ext="edit"></o:lock>
</v:shapetype>
<v:shape id=Picture_x0020_5 style="HEIGHT: 67.5pt; WIDTH: 67.5pt; VISIBILITY: visible; mso-wrap-style: square" alt="Someone's Name" type="#_x0000_t75" o:spid="_x0000_i1025">
  <v:imagedata o:title="Someone's Name" src="file:///C:/Users/USER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image001.jpg"></v:imagedata>
</v:shape>
...HTML continues...
```

Now, I'm sure I can parse this, remove the VML and replace it with an IMG tag, but I'm curious if there's a better way that doesn't require 3rd party libraries and doesn't require any modifications to the registry (this would be running on limited-permission desktops).

Comment: The markup you show us looks a lot like Word Open XML, which makes a certain amount of sense as that would likely be the default for the Clipboard. But Word does put information in multiple formats on the Clipboard, such as BMP. You might query the Clipboard in your code and select the format that gives the best result (pasting into Word I'd use PasteSpecial). I have no code for you, just the idea...

Comment: The clipboard data contains what I see in the resulting pasted document's source view (at least when it comes to the image). I was hoping to avoid reading in the clipboard and parsing out the HTML, and simply rely on native functionality somewhere (if it existed).

Comment: Ah, the image is copied with other content... If only the image were on the Clipboard you might get additional formats. Any HTML Word gives you will be in its "round-trip" format, so it's not going to give you an img tag, unless, perhaps, the graphic is linked and not embedded in the document.